# Is it possible to use LightDM in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, login, lightdm

O we know 11.10 will use LightDM instead of GDM. My question is can I use it in 11.04 already or would that not be advisable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a [PPA for natty](https://launchpad.net/~lightdm-team/+archive/ppa) though [this article](http://www.dreamingisdigital.com/2011/05/12/install-lightdm-on-ubuntu/) warns that it's a development release, may cause problems, etc. so there is some risk at this point.  If you go for it I'd like to hear your results.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion its not advisable to try out LightDM. I have tried it and I have run into issues with my GUI. I had to go into recovery mode and uninstall it. If you want to try it out, use virtualbox .